# Declare a version of a class that has all properties as optional in TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript, types, class-validator

I am using `class-validator` to do type enforcement for a Node api. I have a complex class that uses class-validator decorators, and I want to make a version of this class that represents a draft version, in which all properties are optional. Example:

```
export class Document {
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @Type(() => Author)
  author: Author;

  @IsNotEmpty()
  @ValidateNested({ each: true })
  @Type(() => Section)
  sections: Section[];  
}
```

is the original type and

```
export class DocumentDraft {
  @IsOptional()
  @Type(() => Author)
  author?: Author;

  @IsOptional()
  @ValidateNested({ each: true })
  @Type(() => Section)
  sections?: Section[];  
}
```

Sections here would have other decorated classes as properties, and those need to be optional too. The `Partial` generic in TS produces the desired type, but would lack class validation, right? Am I best off creating a parallel declared class with all the properties decorated with @IsOptional? Must I do this in all the nested types as well?

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by:

1. Creating a recursive partial type:

```
export type RecursivePartial<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]?: RecursivePartial<T[K]>;
};
```

2. Declaring a draft type that is all recursive partial:

```
 type DocumentDraft = RecursivePartial<Document>;
```

3. Then removing all type decoration from the property containing the `Document | DocumentDraft` types

```
  class ParentType {
    document: Document | DocumentDraft;
  }
```

And then using Class Validator manually within the endpoint to only validate properties that exist.